# After 16.04 upgrade, login loop happens

Tags: upgrade, login

After upgrading to 16.04 from 14.04, the usual login screen doesn't come up. Instead, there's a prompt that says

```
login:
```

When I put in my username and then enter the password after, it just goes back to the

```
login:
```

prompt. Does anybody know the cause of this and how I can fix it?

Comment: Don't use all caps. It makes you sound very rude.

Comment: How did you do the upgrade, steps would help.

Comment: check this question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)